# SSRS Adding a Blank Page

Tags: reporting-services

Here is my issue...
I have a report printing off now on a Duplex machine.  I need to add a blank page after every new catalog item.

So example.
Page 1-3 will have catalog A
Page 2-4 will have catalog B

Now normally we will get 4 pages printed out.  But with the printer set to Duplex it is printing only 2 pages.
I want to have Catalog A print on the first two pages and Catalog B will start printing on Page 3 front and back.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a page break after each report?

Or are catalog A and B different groups within the same report? (sorry just need a little more info before i can try to help)

Comment: There is multiple Catalogs that can print off.  I was just using A and B as an example.  I have a matrix setup with multiple groups within it.  I just need a page break with a blank page printed if the Catalog name changes and it is an odd number.